# Excluding container from cache tools

Tags: php, ajax, caching

is there an easy way to exclude a container from caching tools, so the content will display dynamic on every page load?

I have content like this:

```
<div class="dynamic_container">
<?php include 'dynamiccode.php'; ?>
</div>
```

Thanks!